# Interfacing an NRG 40C anemometer to an Arduino

Tags: arduino

This diagram illustrates interfacing an NRG 40C anemometer to an Arduino:

[image: NRG 40C Anemometer Arduino circuit]

<sub>"NRG 40C Anemometer Arduino circuit"</sub>

I hope that someone has an alternative circuit or interface design to help me to reduce the number of electronic components and wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATmega2560 chip has an on-chip comparator so you should be able to use the internal peripheral rather than the LM392, however frankly that circuit you have does not look complete or adequate to protect the input of the LM392 or accommodate the minimum 80mVp-p to 12Vp-p output of the anemometer. More protection is required for the ATmega since it can't accommodate either the positive or negative maximums and the LM392 only has a problem with the negative.

There are probably some important lightning protection considerations that are typically employed if this is going to be mounted on a roof.